# Print a pattern from single long line

Tags: text-processing

For below question, I have tried numerous `grep`/`egrep`,`awk`,`cut` commands but with no luck.

I have a file with only one long line (below is only sample). We want to `grep` below pattern from below file content:

Pattern to be printed:

```
o.buildVersion="2.5.1.162"
```

**Note-** `2.5.1.162` is the unknown part, I only know `o.buildVersion` exists.

**File Content:**

```
    t(t,n){var o=e.call(this,t,n,C.a.FRAMEWORKIDENTIFIER)||this;return o._logger=n,o.resourceBasePath="",o.buildVersion="2.5.1.162".replace(/(\.(?=[^.]*$))(.+)/,""),o.resourceBasePath=t.Cluster.UTIL.getResourceBasePath(),o}return W(t,e),t.prototype.ngOnInit=function(){this._logger.trace("Inside AboutUsComponent!")},t.prototype.ngOnDestroy=function(){this.dispose()},t=X([Object(l.d)({selector:"ignio-about-us",template
```

Comment: `grep -o` seems to be the right tool. What exactly have you tried?

Comment: grep -o, I tried. that printed exact same line which was there. but I wanted to do something like:
cat ffg.js | grep "o.buildVersion"
and expected output:
o.buildVersion="2.5.1.162"

Comment: I tried:\
  880  awk '{for (I=1;I<NF;I++) if ($I == "buildVersion") print $(I+1)}' ignio.ui.45eaf983381f17d17050.js 
 
  
  883  grep -o "Version=" ignio.ui.45eaf983381f17d17050.js 
  884  grep -o "Version=2" ignio.ui.45eaf983381f17d17050.js 
  885  less ignio.ui.45eaf983381f17d17050.js 
  886  o.buildVersion="2.5.1.162"
  887  grep -o "Version=\"2" ignio.ui.45eaf983381f17d17050.js 
  888  grep -o -C 3"Version=\"2" ignio.ui.45eaf983381f17d17050.js 
  889  grep -o -C 3 "Version=\"2" ignio.ui.45eaf983381f17d17050.js 
  892  awk 'FNR>=20 && FNR<=40'  ignio.ui.45eaf983381f17d17050.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the string behind `o.buildVersion` is always enclosed in parentheses, the following `sed` command should work:

```
sed -n -E 's/.*(o\.buildVersion="[^"]*").*/\1/p' input.txt
```

This looks for lines containing `o.buildVersion` and replaces (`s/.../.../`) the entire line with the pattern

```
o.buildVersion="some string"
```

which is enclosed in a "capture group", referred to as `\1` in the replacement text.

In order to ensure we only print matching lines, the option `-n` is used to suppress output by default, and the `p` command to print output for those lines that do match.

Note that extended regular expression syntax is used, so your `sed` needs to understand the `-E` option. If not, use

```
sed -n 's/.*\(o\.buildVersion="[^"]*"\).*/\1/p' input.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

If your `grep` supports the non-standard `-o` and `-P` options, you should be able to use:

```
grep -Po '\bo.buildVersion=".*?"' < your-file
```

To extract all the occurrences of `o.buildVersion="anything"` that don't follow an alnum or underscore, using the `\b` word boundary operator to  avoid picking it up in `capuccino.buildVersion="mild"` for instance.

If there's more than one occurrence, they will be printed one per line.

To limit the result to those in the first line with at least one match, add `-m1` (another non-standard extension from the GNU implementation of `grep`).

To only print the first occurrence on each line:

```
grep -Po '^.*?\K\bo.buildVersion=".*?"'
```

for the last:

```
grep -Po '^.*\K\bo.buildVersion=".*?"'
```

Which both can be combined with `-m1` to stop looking after the first matching line.

To get only the version number:

```
pcregrep -o1 '\bo.buildVersion="(.*?)"' < your-file
```

Or:

```
grep -Po '\bo.buildVersion="\K.*?(?=")' < your-file
```

`-P` is for `perl` regexps here. If your `grep` doesn't support that option, you might as well use the real thing:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 for /\bo.buildVersion="(.*?)"/g' < your-file
```

Or for the first occurrence in the input only:

```
perl -lne 'if (/\bo.buildVersion="(.*?)"/) {print $1; close ARGV}' < your-file
```

One different with the `grep` variants is that if there's no match in the input, it would report a failure exit status. It would be trivial to add if you needed it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `POSIX-only` constructs in sed we incrementally chop off leading portion of the pattern space until we hit the `o.buildVersion=` string. And then print upto the second double quotes.

```
sed -n '
  y/,/\n/
  /^o\.buildVersion=/!D
  s/"/&\
/2;P
' file
o.buildVersion="2.5.1.162"
```